# height issue with position absolute element

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a project for my employer but I am having issues with one of my absolute positioned elements. My page_logo div element will not resize to vertically fill its containing div outside_container. I have read a few things on here and the internet that do not seem to work (mainly setting top, right, bottom, left to 0). I was wondering if you would be able to review the CSS and provide me with some feedback. Just some quick highlights: I have no other positioned elements and only one floated element but it is within another div.

The html structure is below:

```
<html>

    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="header_container"></div>
        <div class="line_seperator"></div>
        <div id="header_text_container"></div>
        <div class="line_seperator"></div>
        <div id="outside_container">
            <!--

             <div id="top_container_inside"> 

            -->
            <div id="page_logo">
                <div class="tileList"></div>
                <!--

                 <div style="clear:both;"></div> 

                -->
            </div>
            <div id="inside_banner">
                <div class="pageTitle">
                    <h1 class="pageTitleH1"></h1>
                    <div id="page_body_container"></div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--

             </div> 

            -->
        </div>
        <div id="footer_container_new"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

relevant CSS

```
#outside_container {
    min-height: 100%;
    height:100%;
}

.tileList{
    position:relative;
    top:5%;
}

#page_logo{
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-color: #09C;
    width: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=94)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=94);
    -moz-opacity:0.94;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.94;
    opacity: 0.94;
}

.pageTitle{
    background-color: #09C;
    width: 68%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float:right;
}

#inside_banner {
    width:99%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CBevD/

Comment: **"I am having issues with one of my absolute positioned elements."** - Perhaps you could actually specify what the **issues** are?

Comment: or atleast provide a fiddle for ease.

Comment: Linking to actual sites, especially when still in development and content can change (you're apparently debugging here) is discouraged.  Go to jsfiddle.net and post code samples there so the error is preserved, as people use this site for reference and may view the post after the issue has gone away.  I posted a general answer that's usually the cause, but if you create a fiddle I can possibly elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

I see two things here.  One is that you aren't specifying a height on `#page_logo`.  Based on your current CSS example you should have the div resizing to 30% width of the parent element `#outside_container` and the height should keep the aspect ratio.  If this is being ignored, or if you have a height being ignored, it's because percent values are relative to the parent container.  If `#outside_container` doesn't have a height then you cannot use a percentage height on the child `#page_logo`.  Likewise, width will have the same issue.